# How to create different instances of a Node.js Application

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i have this idea for an App and i need some configurations on the backend so obviously i decided to go with node.js because that's an option I'm more familiar with, but i need to have different configurations for different clients connected to the application. For example when a client visits the base url, it'll save that users information and use it whenever he visits other routes on the backend. But i can't seem to get that work using express, i have tried socket.io but that doesn't meet my needs. But how does the client side i.e browsers run different instances of the same application but my backend doesn't?... its still javascript, i don't want to use docker images or anything like that, i just want it on the same port is that possible?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where the problem is.

Comment: You can't have two different servers use the same port on the same computer. 
However, you don't need to use separate instances for your back end. For example, you can show different responses depending on who is logged in.

Comment: @SamHerrmann I haven’t tried anything yet, its all just theory, like i said, it's an idea.

Comment: @qrsngky i did think about saving the configurations for each new user logged in then they'll need to pass in some identifier to get those configurations back from where i saved them. but it's all just a tasking process for example if i needed to connect to like a third party API, that'll mean creating a new instance whenever a logged in user visits that route that needs it with his credentials. Is there an easier way to just make it application level instead of every thing the user visits the routes